# Why don't change $_SESSION variables (PHP) when use AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I can not understand a simple problem. Is there a website where I need to add a change of currency on the page (RUR / EUR / USD) using AJAX. I think the best option — it's written in `$_SESSION` selected currency and use it later on my PHP code (for display price, etc).

My `index.php` file:

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 
  if (!isset($_SESSION['currency'])) $_SESSION['currency'] = 'rouble';
?>

<!-- Links -->
<a href="#" class="currency__change" data-currency="dollar">Dollar</a>
<a href="#" class="currency__change" data-currency="euro">Euro</a>
<a href="#" class="currency__change" data-currency="rouble">Rouble</a>

<!-- Add jQuery and script -->
<script src="jquery-2.2.4-min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
```

Here my `ajax.js` file:

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  // On document ready.
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Change currency.
    $('.currency__change').on('click', function(event) {
      // Prevent default.
      event.preventDefault();
      // Send AJAX request.
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Ajax.php',
        data: { 'currency': $(this).data('currency') },
        success: function() {
          location.reload();
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('Error! Try again later.');
        }
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

And now, my `Ajax.php` file:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // Change currency.
  if ($_POST['currency']) {
    unset($_SESSION['currency']);
    $_SESSION['currency'] = $_POST['currency'];
  }
?>
```

Session start normally, I get session file on my server (with default value) with the right headers:

[image]

But if I click AJAX link — variable in `$_SESSION['currency']` don't change.
Why?

Comment: Why `unset` the variable before assign a new value? you dont need to unset the variable, the value of currency is what you expect to be the new value before send the data?, by the way your `if` statement in your `Ajax.php` is not checking nothing, that way works only if the variable has a boolean value like `true` for example, in your case could be `if (isset($_POST['currency']))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that your variable `$(this).data('currency')` is not being set, and your `if ($_POST['currency'])` check is not passing.

Try sending just a string value in for `if ($_POST['currency'])` to test the theory.

```
data: { 'currency': 'Dollar' },
```

you could also put a console.log() in to see if anything is in the variable.

```
console.log("Anything here?",$(this).data('currency'));
```

**Aditionally**

You could implement some php error logging to see what your incoming data looks like.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // Change currency.

  error_log(print_r($_POST,true));

  if ($_POST['currency']) {
    unset($_SESSION['currency']);
    $_SESSION['currency'] = $_POST['currency'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: I checked as you suggested. The result is the same.

Comment: can you share the results of the console logs and php logs?

Answer (score 0):

Session are saved on the server and not on the user browser. To now who is the owner of the session saved session php set a cookie in the user browser called PHPSESSID with a unique id to identify that specific user. When you call the function **session_start()** php use PHPSESSID to load the saved session for that user.

To check if session are working add print of the session in the`index.php` after set the default session.

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 
  if (!isset($_SESSION['currency'])) $_SESSION['currency'] = 'rouble';
?>

<!-- Currency -->
Selected currency: <b><? echo $_SESSION['currency']; ?></b><br>

<!-- Links -->
<a href="#" class="currency__change" data-currency="dollar">Dollar</a>
<a href="#" class="currency__change" data-currency="euro">Euro</a>
<a href="#" class="currency__change" data-currency="rouble">Rouble</a>

<!-- Add jQuery and script -->
<script src="jquery-2.2.4-min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
```

If you need to access to the currency from javascript than you can store it directly in the cookies or crate a javascript function that make a ajax call to php that return the stored currency.

Here you can found how to store and read cookies in javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Here you can found more info on php session: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Some advice:
You don't need to unset the session you can just overwrite it.
You can't use `if($_POST['currency'])` with all php version but fore sure you can do it from the version 5.6